# Center component on jsf page

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I was trying to center the component in jsf page, it looks sth like this:

```
<p:panel header="Enter your credentials:" style="vertical-align:middle;">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="panelGridCenter">
                <h:outputText value="Login: " />
                <p:inplace id="Login">
                    <p:inputText value="Enter login" />
                </p:inplace>
            </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
```

I've tried to enter sth like this:

```
style="vertical-align:middle;"
```

I've tried to use a css class (I've had almost no experience with css):

```
.panelGridCenter {
      margin: 0 auto;
      vertical-align:middle;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Can you give me any examples or hints how to position this component (panel) in  the center of the jsf page?

p - primefaces

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code I will hope this answer be your question

```
<h:form>            
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center"  class="outer_table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="500" height="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <p:panel header="Login">
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

                                        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="username" />
                                        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.uname}" required="true" label="username"/>

                                        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="password" />
                                        <p:password id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" required="true" label="password" />

                                        <p:commandButton value="Login"  action="#{loginBean.loginProject}" update=":growl"/>

                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:panel>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
```

css

```
<script type="text/css">
    html, body
    {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .outer_table
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've used this css class: .loginPanel {
    position: relative; 
    top: 50%; 
    margin-top: 150px; 
    height: 150px; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -180px; 
    width: 360px;
    background-color: #BFFFFE;
} , but it wasn't working until i added <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/cssLayout.css" />

Answer (score 2):

This may be irrelevant as I cannot answer your question, but a dialog (centered by default) looks pretty cool for a login-page:

```
    <h:body>
        <p:growl id="growl" life="5000" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" escape="false"/>

        <h:form>    
            <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Login" footer="..." width="400" widgetVar="dlg" visible="true" closable="false" showEffect="clip" draggable="false" resizable="false" style="box-shadow: 7px 10px 5px #303030;"> 

                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: 0 auto">
                        <h:outputText value="username:"/>            
                        <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" id="username"/>            
                        <h:outputText value="password:"/>            
                        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" id="password"/>            
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton  id="button" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" style="float:right"/>            

            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>   
    </h:body>
```

`visible="true"` makes the dialog show automatically after load.

Inspired by [this](http://www.itcuties.com/j2ee/jsf-2-login-filter-example/) article, also showing how to secure parts of the application.

Comment: Yes, it looks very nice :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but sharing my own experience. After putting the panel into form, try putting the form into div with style as below:

```
<div style="width:360px; margin: 10% auto 10% auto;">
<h:form>
    ....
</h:form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please modify the answer as per the question needs.