# how to properly use css in jsf?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this JSF page with a css file that works fine, however, when i add the form tag css does not apply to the jsf. could someone help me?

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="LoginCss.css" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
         <h:form id="loginForm"> 
              <p:outputLabel id="usernameLabel" value="User name: " />
              <p:inputText id="usernameInput" value=""/> <br/> <br/>

              <p:outputLabel id="passwordLabel" value="Password: " />
              <p:inputText id="passwordInput" value=""/> <br/> <br/>
         </h:form>
    </h:body>

</f:view>
```

Comment: i'm sorry there's a <h:form> </h:form> that is missing. it is : "When i add the <h:form> </h:form> tag css does not..."

Comment: If you open the sourcecode in the browser, try to click on the generated link to the css-file. If it doesn't output the CSS file in question, your link is broken.

Comment: sorry, i didn't catch you, what link? i view the source code in browser and there is the url of css. so i'm not sure if it is broken.

Comment: my problem is that when I add the <h:form> tag the css does not work. what should I do?

Comment: In that case I think you made very specific declarations in your css. Try changing these, at least for testing purposes. For example add `#usernameInput { border: 10px solid red; }`

Comment: actually, that's what I did, like yours.

Comment: Guys, you should know that when writing client side languages like CSS and JavaScript, you should NOT look and base off at the server side source code as it is in server side, but at its generated HTML output as the client side would retrieve. Stop gasping at server side source code, pull the page in webbrowser and do rightclick and *View Source*. THAT, the generated HTML output, is exactly what client side languages like CSS and JavaScript are actually seeing. Last but not least, using IDs to select and style common elements is bad design. Just select common elements by class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate on BalusC's comment: After you add the form, JSF will prepend the id of the form to its children's id's, so the first inputText will now have `id="loginForm:usernameInput"` (as you can see with "show source" or similar in the browser).

Since this breaks the styling I expect you currently use the id for styling. Much better practice is to use the `styleClass` attribute instead. Also you would probably want to bind the inputText's to bean properties in the `value` attribute. Further suggestions are to use a `p:panelGrid` and a `p:password` for the password:

```
.usernameInput {
    ...
}
.passwordInput {
    ...
}
```

and

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel id="usernameLabel" for="usernameInput" value="User name: " />
    <p:inputText id="usernameInput" styleClass="usernameInput" value="#{bean.username}"/>
    <p:outputLabel id="passwordLabel" for="passwordInput" value="Password: " />
    <p:password id="passwordInput" styleClass="passwordInput" value="#{bean.password}"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I could also change the value of prependId of the form to false.

Comment: Yes you are completely right, but I think it will still be better to use the class as its best practice. Btw you could also create your loginpage with a dialog like here, then it will be centered automatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314745/center-component-on-jsf-page/24315632#24315632

Comment: Avoid `prependId="false"` in JSF2. It breaks ajax things. They should have made this JSF1+JSP specific feature deprecated in JSF2.